# Prove that $d_X/ d_Y = |Y |/ |X|$ for certain bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a bipartite
graph with vertices partitioned $$V = X \sqcup Y,$$  and assume: every x in X has the same degree $d_X ≥ 1$, and every y in Y has the same degree $d_Y ≥ 1$.
Prove that $$\frac{d_X}{d_Y} =\frac{|Y|}{|X|}$$

I tried 4 conditions:
(1) $|X|=|Y|$ while $d_X=d_Y$,
(2) $|X|=|Y|$ while $d_X\ne d_Y$,
(3) $|X|\ne |Y|$ while $d_X=d_Y$, and
(4) $|X|\ne |Y|$ while $d_X\ne d_Y$.

(1) is obvious and true, (2) and (3) I'm not so sure about. It seems impossible for (2) seeing as how if the cardinality is the same, you'll always have a perfect matching. It seems like (3) would be impossible too because you'll always have extra nodes that mess up the degree of the other side. (4) I know is possible in some situations and right now it seems only possible if there's a perfect matching.

Comment: I tried 4 conditions, (1) |x|=|y| while dx=dy, (2) |x|=|y| while dx=/=dy, (3) |x|=/=|y| while dx=dy, and (4) |x|=/=|y| while dx=/=dy. (1) is obvious and true, (2) and (3) I'm not so sure about. It seems impossible for (2) seeing as how if the cardinality is the same, you'll always have a perfect matching. It seems like (3) would be impossible too because you'll always have extra nodes that mess up the degree of the other side. (4) I know is possible in some situations and right now it seems only possible if there's a perfect matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is bipartite, meaning that all edges cross between $X$ and $Y$. Given that the degree of every vertex in $X$ is $d_X$, there must be exactly $|X|d_X$ edges, and the same goes for $Y$. Thus

$$ |E| = |X|d_X=|Y|d_Y$$

and the result follows.